# Best practice to store diverse time intervals in OLAP cube

Tags: database-design, olap

My task is to make "OLAP cube", aggregated by time intervals

**So, it is supposed, that facts table will store aggregates:**

1. for each day
2. for each month based on its days records
3. for each year based on its months records

**And it will look like this:**

```
|------------------------------------------|
|   id |  day | month | year | total_sales |
|------------------------------------------|
|    1 |    1 |     1 | 2020 |          10 |
|    2 |    2 |     1 | 2020 |          10 |
| ...N | ...N |  ...N | 2020 |          10 |
|   32 | null |     1 | 2020 |         310 |  # total for Jan 2020
| ...N | null |  ...N | 2020 |         300 |
|  378 | null |  null | 2020 |        3600 |  # total for 2020
|------------------------------------------|
```

So, is that a good plan in general?

Will it be better to make day, month, year as a standalone dimension, or it does not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not  good idea, in most cases, to mix facts of differing granularity in a single fact table.  If you really need to store daily, monthly and yearly data, consider more than one fact table.

You can also have a dimension table with one row per day and various attributes that facilitate aggregation, such as fiscal year.

Comment: So, would you recommend to describe one model `BaseAggregatedFacts` and inherit to `AggregatedFactsPerDay`, `AggregatedFactsPerMonth`, `AggregatedFactsPerYear`? Btw, why is it a bad idea to store in one table?

Comment: It makes retrieval much harder, in the environments I can think of.  I'm thinking mainly of star schema in an SQL database.  There may be some OLAP oriented data stores where my objection does not apply.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by inherit.

Comment: Sry, I mean inherit in context of MVP's ORM-Model class, so keep similar tables, described by one abstraction, but with different names

Comment: OK, I can't help you with MVP.  Sorry.